# is use parcelable with entity room and API post is wrong?

Tags: android, firebase, performance

I read in doc on android developer it says

> Note: Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism, and you should never store any Parcel data on disk or send it over the network.
> [Android dev doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles)

I have Address class for example
I use it in save in database and post in remote data base

```
    @Entity
@Parcelize
data class Address(
    val city: String = "",
    val address: String = "",
    val description: String = "",
    val phone: String = "",
    @PrimaryKey
    val uid: String = "",
) : Parcelable
```

all property has value because in firestore to use auto serialization and deserialization

1 - is it ok ?

Comment: What they are trying to say is as long as you are just using it to pass information in bundles to an activity for example its fine. Other cases you should use serialization methods more made for persisting/sending data like gson or kotlinx serialization. Room does its own serialization

Comment: yes I use it in fragment when navigate another fragment I need parcelize data I think it is better  then create another call from remote data base or local right?